# retrive the the data which modified in specific column along with secong max updated date in sybase sql

Tags: sap-ase, sap-iq

I have the data
column name status1 status2 status3 update_date user
Row1   A    1       2       3       06/05/2017  A
Row2   A    1       3       3       05/05/2017  C
Row3   A    5       2       3       03/05/2017  A
Row4   A    2       3       3       02/05/2017  B
Row5   A    2       2       1       01/05/2017  A

THE EXPECTED RESULT IS:

i want to retrive the data modified in status1(specific) and its last modified date along with before modification which data it had on specific date(04/05/2014)
Ex:

Row3   A    5       2       3       03/05/2017  A
Row4   A    2       3       3       02/05/2017  B

as you can see in row 3 the status1 lastly updated on 03/05/2017 by the user A (I want this data)
as well as in row 4 before the update it had a data of row 4

could you help me on this?

Comment: Are you using ASE or IQ? The answers may not be the same.  Also..how have you attempted to solve this?  Have you looked at triggers?

Comment: yes I checked triggers, but having an issue with the update time ,
 found strange in updated timeings , more than 3 records are updated by different logins, such like many rows I can see for different profiles
Im not sure how it is possible

Comment: finally I found one way to get the data updated on specific time,
still trying to get the data before update as had an contra in update time only few ms by the same users...

Comment: could you share me how to retrieve data not updated at the specific time and its around timings

for this  19/10/2016 10:14:58, I need to retrieve data not updated in around 10-15 mins,